# Calculating standard deviation

Tags: performance, c

I am getting about 215 MB/s throughput on this implementation of [Welford's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithms_for_calculating_variance). My hard drive is rated for 400 MB/s reads, so I am wondering how I can optimise this. I assume the bottleneck is in `getline` or `atof` as 400 MB/s throughput gives my 4 GHz processor 640 cycles per double to work with, which should be more than enough for the computational part of the loop. Are there faster alternatives?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if (argc != 1) {
        printf("Usage: %s < data\n", argv[0]);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    size_t count = 0;
    double mean = 0;
    double m2 = 0;

    char *line = NULL;
    size_t len = 0;
    ssize_t nread;

    while ((nread = getline(&line, &len, stdin)) != -1) {
        double newValue = atof(line);
        count++;
        double delta = newValue - mean;
        mean += delta / count;
        m2 += delta * (newValue - mean);
    }

    printf("%lf\n%lf\n", mean, sqrt(m2 / count));

    free(line);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you profiled or do a benchmark to find out where in your code most of the time is spent?  In most programs involving I/O, the I/O is the bottleneck.  If you can use block reading.  The `getline` doesn't block read; it actually is scanning for a ending sentinel; which slows down the input process.

Comment: I have rolled back your last edit. Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Avoid intermediate copies

By using `getline()` you make a copy of some characters into a temporary buffer, then you call `atof()` on that. There is some overhead in that. You could consider doing this instead:

```
while(scanf("%lf ", &newValue) == 1) {
    …
}
```

Which may or may not be faster. Note that `getline()` also allocates heap memory for the buffer, which probably doesn't matter much since it will only do it a few times at most, but it could be avoided by using a fixed-size array; after all, numbers are only so big.

## Use a better floating point number parser

The standard library might not have an optimal algorithm to convert strings to floating point values, and apart from that it might take into account [locales](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locale_(computer_software)), which adds some overhead. In recent years some advances have been made in string-to-float algorithms, and some (standard) libraries also have functions to parse numbers without bothering with locales. The C++ library for example has gotten [`std::from_chars()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/from_chars). You might also want to look at external libaries, like [Daniel Lemire's fast_double_parser](https://github.com/lemire/fast_double_parser).

## Use multiple threads

Even if you can make the parsing so fast that your program is purely I/O bound, you might still get a benefit from making it multi-threaded. That's because SSDs nowadays can work faster if they receive multiple I/O requests to different parts of the SSD.

## Missing error checking

Your should check after the `while`-loop that `feof(stdin) == true`, to verify that you actually read all the way to the end of the file. If it's `false`, that means an error occured, in which case you should not print out an incorrect standard deviation, but print an error message to `stderr` and return `EXIT_FAILURE`.

Note that parsing a number might fail as well (maybe the file containing the data was corrupted for example, or it's not a file with numbers at all), so it would be better if you could check for those kinds of errors as well, although it will come at some cost to performance.

Answer (score 6):

The calculations appear to use the numerically stable formulae from equations (4) and (24) in *[Incremental calculation of weighted mean and variance](https://fanf2.user.srcf.net/hermes/doc/antiforgery/stats.pdf)* - well done for avoiding the mathematician's version that suffers from catastrophic cancellation in floating-point arithmetic.

However, the correspondence isn't immediately obvious here:

```
        m2 += delta * (newValue - mean);
```

Because we assigned `delta == newValue - mean`, it looks like this is the same as `delta * delta`.  However, because `mean` has been modified in between, it's not equivalent.  Perhaps it's worth renaming `delta` to `delta_pre` and creating an new `delta_post` to make this absolutely clear (and prevent a subsequent maintainer from "correcting" the code):

```
        double new_value = atof(line);
        double const delta_pre = new_value - mean;
        mean += delta_pre / ++count;

        double const delta_post = new_value - mean;
        m2 += delta_pre * delta_post;
```

---

Minor things:

- Error message should go to stderr, not stdout:

  ```
      if (argc != 1) {
          fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s < data\n", argv[0]);
  ```

  The message is perhaps misleading as there are other ways of providing data on standard input, such as here-strings or pipes.
- We could return `EXIT_SUCCESS` instead of magic number `0` at the end, to be more consistent with the error return.  Or just omit the `return` statement - `main()` is magic and will return success just by executing off the end.

Comment: Hmmm, with no `return` on `main()` then "function returns a value of 0."  § 5.1.2.2.3 1.  `EXIT_SUCCESS` is not defined as 0 but with use with `exit()`: "`EXIT_SUCCESS` which expand to integer constant expressions that can be used as the argument to the exit function" and implies it might differ from 0: "If the value of status is zero or EXIT_SUCCESS": Curiously, the spec does _not_ talk about `return EXIT_SUCCESS;` in `main()`.  I wonder 1) if that is UB 2) Has any implementation done `EXIT_SUCCESS != 0`?  Think I will stay with `return 0;` for now.

Comment: Ooh, that's worthy of a language-lawyer question over on [so], I think.

Comment: The spec _does_ define the behaviour of `return EXIT_SUCCESS;` albeit indirectly: "_a return from the initial call
to the `main` function **is equivalent to** calling the `exit` function with the value returned by the `main`
function as its argument_" (my emphasis).  I guess that `EXIT_SUCCESS` is to successful exit somewhat as `NULL` is to null pointers: a macro that doesn't necessarily expand to `0` but causes the same behaviour as `0`.

Answer (score 6):

**Missing assessment**

OP's goal is "how I can optimise this.", yet post lacks a test harness.  Posting code that reports the performance allows us all to post real results rather than a bunch of theoretical improvements and ideas.

**Fixed point printing**

`printf("%lf\n%lf\n", mean, sqrt(m2 / count));` hints that precision is not the real the goal.

Printing *floating point* numbers with *fixed point* format prints about 25% of `double` as 0.000000 and 25% of large values with excessive precision.

Use `"%.16e"`, `"%.17g"` or `"%a"` for more informative results.

---

**Simplify algorithm**

Consider base-lining with the basic [naive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithms_for_calculating_variance#Na%C3%AFve_algorithm) algorithm.

```
while ((nread = getline(&line, &len, stdin)) != -1) {
    double newValue = atof(line);
    sum += newValue;
    sum_squared += newValue * newValue;
    count++;
}
printf("Average: %g\n", sum/count);
printf("Variance: %g\n", (sum_squared − (sum*sum) / count) / (count − 1));
```

Depending on the data set, the 64-bit `double` math with the simpler algorithm may render a sufficiently precise and speedier answer.

Part of the reason for the 15+ decimal digits of precision for `double` is so one does not need to perform precision preservating code and instead go for direct fast encoding.

**`float`**

Using `float` vs. `double` is often faster (4x even).  Much depends on the underlying hardware, yet worth a try.

**Time for I/O**

Timing a simple read-only would help gauge how much time is spent reading.

```
clock_t c0 = clock();
while ((nread = getline(&line, &len, stdin)) != -1) {
  ;
}
clock_t c1 = clock();
printf("time: %g seconds\n", 1.0*(c1 - c0)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
```

---

**`size_t`?**

Unclear why code uses `size_t` to count the values.  `size_t` correlates with *memory* size. I suppose some type that goes along with *file* size is useful.  `unsigned long` is a reasonable alternative given `ftell()` returns `long`.

With the naïve approach, might as well use `uintmax_t`.

Comment: Regarding item count: on some systems (e. g. Windows), `size_t` and/or `unsigned long` cannot hold the amount of records that may occur in a file. Possible alternatives are `off_t` (the return type of `ftello()` which is meant to supersede `ftell()`) and `uintmax_t` which are guaranteed to hold the maximum supported file size on a platform.

Comment: @DavidFoerster `off_t`, `ftello()` are not part of the standard C library.  Concerning "on some systems (e. g. Windows)", I'd say the issue is a compiler one, not an OS one.  I find no specified guarantee that `uintmax_t` is sufficiently large for all file sizes, yet it is very reasonable and practical to assume that.

Answer (score 3):

#### Profile to Find the Bottleneck

Others have already made this point, but you need to find where your program is spending all its time, and focus on that.

#### Look for Ways to Speed up the I/O

This is going to be implementation-dependent, but in many cases, `fscanf()`, which doesn’t need to copy or heap-allocate, can be faster than `getline()`.  In fact, you currently allocate and free a buffer from the heap for every data point.

Not in the standard library, your OS, or a third-party library like glib, probably lets you memory-map a regular file. That lets you scan for tokens and pass the beginning and end of each token to `strtod`.  This can be extremely fast because there is no buffering or copying, just mapping the pages of the file on disk to memory similarly to the virtual memory manager.  (G. Sliepen had an excellent series of comments, now removed, pointing out the ways that might not be true.)

#### Store the Data Points in a Dynamic Array

Instead of reading each value in one at a time, you want to store all the scanned values in memory (maximizing the I/O throughput) and then process them at once (allowing parallelization and SIMD).

It’s possible to implement a resizing vector of `double` in C, and that’s probably the data structure you want for this, although you might also make two passes through the file in memory, one to count the items, and then another to fill the array.

#### Parallelizing the Calculation

The version of the calculation that you’re using is incremental, and therefore inherently serial.  If you have all the data in memory, however, there is no need to use an incremental formula.  You can make two passes, one reduction to calculate the mean, and then another to calculate the variance as a map-reduction (the sum of (*xᵢ-μ*)² for all *xᵢ*), and finally calculate σ from the variance.  You will then be adding the squares of small differences, which all have the same sign, and not get any subtractive cancellation from this step (although there could be large data points with opposite signs making the calculation of the mean numerically unstable).  This version of the calculation sacrifices some stability for being able to use SIMD.

You can additionally split the both passes between threads, with OpenMP, or calculate the variance of each subrange of the input and then the total variance from those.  Since the mean and variance can be calculated from simple sums of terms, you could use the reduction operation of OpenMP for this (or in the C++ standard library, `std::transform_reduce` with a parallel execution policy), rather than a weighted-mean and weighted-variance formula.  Otherwise, you would want to partition the input array into one slice per worker thread.

While the way I outlined above sacrifices some numerical stability for the speed of SIMD, you might figure out an incremental formula that adds four terms at once, or however many your hardware can efficiently vectorize.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147278/discussion-on-answer-by-davislor-calculating-standard-deviation); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 0):

The standard library functions often have features which make them nice to use but also introduce overhead. If this is for competitive programming, your input number format is probably very simple, and you can take advantage of this by handling everything manually. Allocate a buffer, say a megabyte, do an `fread` into it, and parse the buffer with simple logic like `if (buffer[position] >= '0' && buffer[position] <= '9')`. Make sure to handle the case of a number spanning the end of one read and beginning of another.

If this is going to run in production, I'd keep it as it is, except I'd replace `atof` with `strtod` in order to do a bit of error checking. It's slower than manually parsing a buffer, but it's harder to make a programming mistake this way.